# Is there a way to simplify further the following excel formula?

Tags: excel

```
=IF(AND(OR(A=x, B=x), C=y), TRUE, FALSE)
```

I'm trying to figure out if I can simplify this statement so I'm not repeating the same value (x) multiple times in my OR statement.

Something like "If A and B are equal to x, and C is equal to y, then return TRUE."

EDIT: I should add that I'm using tables and header references:

```
=IF(AND(OR([Column1]=x, [Column2]=x), [Column3]=y), TRUE, FALSE)
```

That should make it easier to reply, sorry. I don't need to worry with bothersome cell ranges.

My "algorithm" which I've represented by "x" is just a number of date and cell comparisons and inventory properties that result in a non-zero integer.

Comment: It needs the row numbers of course, but something like this would work, though what you have is already very efficient: `=1=((COUNTIF(A:B,x)>0)*(C=y))`

Comment: Just a comment too - while @tigeravatar may have a more efficient formula, I'd stick to yours since it's more easily understandable. This is especially important if other users will use it.  I can easily understand yours, but it takes a few more little grey cells to figure out how tiger's works.

Comment: mine is not very efficient in my case, where "x" is an algorithm.

Comment: @Dexter Does dashnick's solution work for you? If so, please mark that as correct answer.  If not, please edit your question to include more details.  This is the first we've heard that `"x" is an algorithm`

Comment: @Dexter, put your algorithm in a cell then use the cell reference in place of `x` then you only need to type it once.

Comment: I'm on my way home, so I'll give all these a shot and comment back. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify further by using a VLOOKUP table:

```
AND(NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(x,$A$1:$B$2,2,false))), C=y)
```

Where the values for A and B and their truth values are stored in locations
 $A$1:$B$2

Comment: A simple table can be included as an array literal `=VLOOKUP(3, {2,"blue";3,"red"}, 2, FALSE)`

Comment: @TimWilliams: Cool! When did that enter the application?

Comment: I don't think it's new, but relatively "new" to me...   See: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-array-constants-in-array-formulas-477443ea-5e71-4242-877d-fcae47454eb8

Comment: @TimWilliams: Google references to it go back only a few years, so I am guessing either 2010 or 2013.

Comment: I'd say at least back to Excel 97: http://www.angelfire.com/oh3/SunnyCee/office/excel/arrays.html

Comment: I added an edit to show how I'm referring to "A" using my Column reference from my table headers. Don't even need VLookup! Edit: Nevermind, I didn't see the value of VLookup using "x" for comparison

Comment: This works great. It did not work for my situation, even with the array literal, but that's because I'm unable to figure out how to use structured references inside the array (my columns might not be adjacent, as I have no control over the data once this gets implemented). I decided to go with @Scott Craner's suggestion of putting my algorithm into a cell.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the `IF()`, because the comparison already returns `true`/`false`.  So

```
=AND(OR(A=x, B=x), C=y)
```

That's the simplest it could be, since there are logically 3 comparisons.

**Update:** if you want to get rid of using the `x` twice, use an array formula, like:

```
=AND(OR(x=D6:D7), C=y)
```

entered using `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`.  Note here `a` and `b` would be in adjacent cells `D6` and `D7`.  (I don't know of a way to construct an array out of named ranges in a formula.)

Comment: Ooh nice.  But you'd need the `If()`, if you wanted to return some string, or cell value, etc. yeah?

Comment: The problem is that the OP was hoping for something where `x` is only typed once, in that `x` probably some long formula or something.